Why does my angular app hosted on nginx with docker doesn't work?
I've been trying to host an angular app on nginx with docker during this past week but i couldnt get through it.
This is mi dockerfile:
your textFROM node:latest as build                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 your textWORKDIR /usr/local/app                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    your textCOPY ./ /usr/local/app/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   your textRUN npm install                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           your textRUN npm install -g @angular/cli                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           your textCMD ["npm", "start"]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   your textFROM nginx:latest                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         your textRUN rm /usr/share/nginx/html/*                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            your textCOPY --from=build /usr/local/app/dist/prueba /usr/share/nginx/html                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        your textRUN rm etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      your textCOPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      your textEXPOSE 80
this is my default.conf file:
your textserver {
your textlisten 80;
your textserver_name app;
your textlocation / {
your textproxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
your textproxy_http_version 1.1;
your textproxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
your textproxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
your textproxy_set_header Host $host;
your textproxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
your text}
}

You need to reformat those files. Enclose each in triple-backtics ``` before and after the file contents, and remove all the trailing spaces at the end of each line. | Then, describe what "doesn't work" means.  I doubt anyone can figure out what's wrong using only the docker file and conf file.
